# zoomcharts - netcharts group nodes

Tags: zoomcharts

I have two questions in using the zoomcharts.

Is there a way to group nodes and display the group and on zoom-in display the specific nodes?

Also, is there a way to draw hierarchical network?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

hierachical network layout is on our road map and should be available in q1-q2, 2015.

grouping of nodes is likewise on our road map. I can suggest following zoomcharts twitter/facebook to get information when new features are available.

yesterday we released 1.3 version that contains lots of interesting improvements and bunch of new features.